# @page :first not working in css

Tags: html, css, media

With the print button, I am printing the HTML page with some header and footer having `@media print` rule.

I want header different for the first page and same on other pages. For this I am trying `@page :first` rule.

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

@media screen {
  header.onlyprint,
  header.onlyprintf,
  footer.onlyprint {
    display: none;
    /* Hide from screen */
  }
}

.p {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  #myHeader {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .p {
    display: initial;
  }
  .np {
    display: none;
  }
  a[href]:after {
    display: none;
  }
  header.onlyprint {
    position: fixed;
    /* Display only on print page (each) */
    top: 0;
    /* Because it's header */
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  footer.onlyprint {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    /* Because it's footer */
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%
  }
  @page :first {
    header.onlyprint {
      display: none;
    }
    header.onlyprintf {
      position: relative;
      /* Display only on print page (each) */
      top: 0;
      /* Because it's header */
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="btn btn-large btn-success np" onClick="window.print()" style="position: fixed; top: 75px; left: 50%;">Print</button>
  <header class="onlyprint">Header</header>
  <footer class="onlyprint">Footer</footer>
  <header class="onlyprintf">First Page Header</header>
  Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text
  Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some
  Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br
  />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text
  Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some
  Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br
  />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text
  Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />Some Text Here<br />
```

Comment: What browser(s) have you tested this in?

Comment: @Quentin I am testing it in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first):

> Note: You can't change all CSS properties with this pseudo-class. You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document. Furthermore, you may only use absolute-length units when defining the margins. All other properties will be ignored.

I'm not aware of any way to change the rendering of a specific element based upon the page it appears on.

This is likely due to the ability to change if it is on the first page or not.

i.e. If you give an element `margin-top: 50cm` if it is on the first page, then it is no longer on the first page, so `margin-top: 50cm` is no longer applied, which means it **is** on the first page so `margin-top: 50cm` *does* apply and loop forever.

CSS tries to make it impossible to express that type of logic error.

Comment: So how can I have, a different header on the first page? **Note:** The headers are to be only displayed in print, not on screen.

Comment: "I'm not aware of any way to change the rendering of a specific element based upon the page it appears on."